# How to send data from popup to parent window

Tags: php, javascript

I want to open a popup on pageload .In this popup people can fill data in dropdown for city and locality.

After closing this popup this data should be sent to my parent window where I have a form which contain city and locality textbox.

No I want to implement this using php and javascript.pls suggest.

Comment: Using `window.parent`

Answer (score 1):

Put this echo code at php end of child window,

```
 echo '<script type="text/javascript">
               window.opener.function_name_of_parent_window('.json_encode($user_data).');
               window.close();
              </script>';
```

That will call your desired function on parent window and data that you want to send over there as parameter

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest modal windows (because now browsers block onload popups) and ajax. PHP here is not required, as everything can be implemented in client side

Answer (score 0):

You should with javascript be able to set a variable on the parent page using:

parent.data = localdata

however, why do you want to use a popup window in the first place.  A popup layer would be much cleaner and wouldn't be blocked by popup blockers